# CORS in my node app not working

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-504

A website is doing a XMLHttpRequest to my node app, but they are getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[MY IP]/start. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.[THEIR WEBSITE].com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 504.
```

This is their XMLHttpRequest request:

```
var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest === "undefined" ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest; 
xhr.open("POST", 'http://[MY IP]/myapp', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This is the code in the node app (the ... represents irrelevant code):

```
...
var cors = require('cors')
...
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');
  next();
});

app.post('/myapp', function (req, res) {
  var data = req.body;
  console.log(data);
  res.status(200);
});
```

Do you have any idea why this isn't working?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Why ain't you making use of cors library?

Comment: I am? var cors = require('cors')

Answer (score 1):

I am the person who created this question.

I figured out the answer.

If a XMLHttpRequest open request is set to asynchronous (third parameter set to 'true'), the node app must send a response. A status code is not enough. You must provide some sort of response. Otherwise you get a 504 timeout error.

EDIT: You can use **res.sendStatus(200)**. My error was I was just doing res.status(200).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `OPTIONS` as one of the methods allowed.

Basically replace `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');` with `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,POST');`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this, but I still have the same problem. My app is behind a nginx reverse proxy. Could that be affecting things?

Comment: Probably. Can you post the headers that your app is getting back from the server?

Comment: The response is blank. I'm getting a 504 (timeout) error. Yet if I try to access my node app using a simple GET request, it works fine. Weird...

Comment: I figured it out. Please see below!